# How to implement mp4 animation on ios splash screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to know how to replace splash screen to mp4 movie.

If possible, tell me how with code, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this isnt possible under iOS (maybe one day)

what many apps do to simulate it is load the first frame of the video statically as a png splash screen and then finish really quick and return YES from applicationDidFinishLaunching even before they load ANYTHING :D

THEN they show the video in a fullscreen view and in the bg, load the app for real!

---

1. have a static image as a Default.png
2. wait for the call applicationDidFinishLaunching:
3. place a movie view fullscreen and play your video
   3b. start loading the app for real : the view controllers, the core data stack, ... whatever
4. wait for a call to applicationDidReallyLaunch (or whatever you choose to name it), remove the video

Answer (score 0):

1. synchronized Default.png Image and mp4 Video first screen.
2. using a AVPlayer play mp4 Video Full Screen when called application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
3. video, if player did Reach End, remove AVPlayer Object.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to splash screen as mp4 animation, then there is no meaning of splash screen. because

> Basically, a splash screen is an image of what your application looks
>   like when it is loaded for the first time. Using a splash screen
>   ensures that while your application is being loaded, the user is not
>   starting at a blank screen. Instead, the splash screen is displayed.
>   This engages the user with your application immediately. When it is
>   fully loaded, the splash screen then disappears, and your application
>   displays its first screen, ready to use.This improves the user
>   experience by creating the impression that your application
>   loads immediately.
>
> While Apple has explicitly stated that the splash screen is meant to
>   improve the user experience of your application, not to display a
>   “splash screen” for it .but a lot of developers are making use of this
>   feature to display splash screens for their applications.

if you want to show at starting then show only first frame of video as splash screen & then start your mp4 animation in really.